# how do you count the number of results

Tags: counting

Write a program that reads a series of numbers, ending with 0, and then tells you how
many numbers you have keyed in (other than the last 0). For example, if you keyed in
the numbers 5, -10, 50, 22, -945, 12, 0 it would output ‘You have entered 6 numbers.’.

doing my homework and can get this one to work

what stumps me is i understand adding the numbers to get the sum total but what do i call the number of numbers ...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python has a very simple function that could be used here, [string.count()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm). Given each number is separated by a comma, you can count the amount of commas to get the amount of numbers (not including the 0, which doesn't have a comma after it). An example of this in use would be

```
input = 5, -10, 50, 22, -945, 12, 0
Number_of_Numbers = input.count(',')
```

Comment: thanks for answer but the output will come out as each number then the question again and then the number .... until you type zero which then adds the loop

Comment: So the user is typing in a number, submitting that number, and then it asks them for a new number? Every time they submit a number add 1 to a variable then, until they enter 0